# recursive to iterative (java)

Tags: java, recursion

as a beginner in programming I am trying to convert the following recursive method to an iterative one but I just don't get the hang of it. The method or function has a binary tree like recursion and I would like to use an array for the iterative solution.. unfortunately I am very confused how to do it.

I have already checked the way of converting the fibonnaci recursive method to an iterative one. But I think this is not the same here. Also I am not sure if a tree search method is useful?! Any help, hint, idea would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
public static int funct(int n) {

  if (n == 0) return 1;
  if (n == 1) return 2;
  if n > 1 return funct(n-2)*funct(n/2);

}
```

Comment: fibonacci or binary tree?. What is the question about ?

Comment: funct(n/2)? What if n is odd? That is a strange function you have here

Comment: Integer division?

Comment: @fge it seems it's related to [A242634](https://oeis.org/A242634) where the answer is `2^A242634(n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now the real function is without last if:

```
public static int funct(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    if (n == 1) return 2;
    return funct(n-2) * funct(n/2);
}
```

As the recursive calls refer to smaller parameters one can cache all return values upto n.

Unfortunately this already spoils the pleasure, as the resulting code is complete:

```
public static int funct(int n) {
    int[] results = new int[n+1];
    results[0] = 1;
    results[1] = 2;
    int i = 2;
    while (i <= n) {
        results[i] = results[i-2] * results[i/2];
        ++i;
    }
    return results[n];
}
```

It indeed looks like fibonacci.

In general one would not need to fill all items of `results`. like probably `results[n - 1]`.
Unfortunately you should have learnt prior to this problem:

- Solving tail recursion.
- Using a stack (like here) to use inner results of a recurive call.

You might look into those topics.

---

***Math afterlude***

The initial values are powers of 2. As the result is a *product* of earlier results, all results will be powers of 2.

```
f(0) = 1 = 2^0
f(1) = 2 = 2^1
f(n) = f(n - 2) * f(n / 2)
```

Hence you can introduce:

```
g(0) = 0
g(1) = 1
g(n) = g(n - 2) + g(n / 2)
f(n) = 2^g(n)
```

This will enlarge the range you can calculate as say **2<sup>100</sup>**.

You will also see:

```
g(2k + 1) = g(2k) + 1
```

So you will only need a domain of even numbers:

```
g(2k) = g(2(k-1)) + g(k - k%2) + k%2
```

Comment: you should also increment i in the while loop

Comment: @user1121883 now it is infinitely better.

Comment: @joop just miss the link :)

Comment: @JekinKalariya tail recursion in wikipedia was not very convincing for me, and stack is more or less what I did. We both know that simple math will yield some power of 2 formula `f(n) = 2^{n-2   + [(n-8):2].[(n-6):2] / 2} given n > 5`with integer division and a sum `1+2+3+...+k`. (Not sure whether I got it right.) It would indeed be nice to show that math derivation, but the OP has to do that work himself.

Comment: @Joop: Thanks.. that's really great.. I very much like your implementation!  I definitely will have a look at the mentioned topics of tail recursion and use of stack. I am also thinking to optimize the size of the array. I don't know if this has any benefit but one can set the length to max(n-2, n/2) + 1. What do you think?

Comment: For large n irrelevant, but for n < 2 it should be `max(2, n+1)`. You could do some math, I will add.

Answer (score 8):

Since every n-th member is computed by others before if you can cache all in a list. You start by adding the first 2 known members. Fibonacci its easier because you always need only previous value.

```
private static int func(int n) {
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(n+1);
    values.add(1);
    values.add(2);
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        values.add(values.get(i - 2) * values.get(i / 2));
    }

    return values.get(n);
}
```

Comment: That's the answer.

Comment: I was thinking using a while with a Stack, but yours looks btter

Comment: super solution with super logic